# How to add an overlay DIV to cover an existing DIV (using JQuery)?

Tags: jquery, overlay

I have a 'container' DIV which may have all possible CSS styles like: margin, padding, border and different position (fixed, relative, absolute).

I want to show a loading icon above the 'container' DIV and forbid the user to operate any control in the 'container' DIV.

```
<div class="container">
 A lot of content here ...
</div>
```

How can I add an overlay DIV (using JQuery) which covers the entire 'container' DIV visible area (margin area should not be covered)?

Best regards,
Zach

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If nothing to change in CSS, then:

```
$("<div />").css({
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    zIndex: 1000000,  // to be on the safe side
    background: "url(/img/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%"
}).appendTo($(".container").css("position", "relative"));
```

```js
$("<div>Loading...</div>").css({
  position: "absolute",
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  background: "#ccc"
}).appendTo($(".container").css("position", "relative"));
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  A lot of content here ...
</div>
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/jKfTC/

Comment: Also might be a good idea to check if the `.container` has 'static' positioning before setting it's position... just to make your code reusable.

Comment: I would recommend having all your styling defined before in your css file rather than applying it on the fly with jQuery. Like so http://jsfiddle.net/jKfTC/1/

Comment: If the container has a border, the border is not covered in the solution above.

Comment: You could just make the loading container span 1px bigger all the way around like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jKfTC/3/

Comment: Also it's z-index not zIndex, for all ya noobs out there!

Comment: @Cody It is `z-index` for CSS file and for inline styles of HTML elements. In JavaScript you may use `zIndex` property of `style` object. jQuery can accept both `"z-index"` (key as a string) and `zIndex` (as simple as that).